# Background not appearing when rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to add a sky to my scene but it won't appear in the render. I've tried:

- Adding a sky using the sky and atmosphere options when creating a sun lamp
- Adding a sky by going to the world panel and using paper sky / blend sky

All I get is this default background:

[image]

Comment: If you are in cycles render,go to render>film and uncheck the transparent.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure *Alpha* is set to *Sky* in *Render settings > Shading*:

[image]

And *Sky* is enabled in *Render Layers > Layer*:

[image]